# Mail is not sending from website

Tags: php, email

I have using php for sending mail..

I am not getting any error but mail is not receiving.

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

I have given all the objects(email from and to and message.).

If i print @mail(), It is showing **true** but not getting mail

This is godaddy account servergo

Comment: did you check mail in spam or junk box?

Comment: "I am not getting any error" do you know what the **@** does?

Comment: I am also not getting any error. but mail is not coming even spam also.

Comment: Personally suggest to use PHPMailer. See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: If i try this, It is showing smtp connection failed